# How to rewrite a broken URL path that begins with "%22http://"?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm getting requests to broken URLs like:

http://www.example.com/%22http:/www.example.com/how-to-keep-your-teeth-free-of-stains.html

which I want redirect to:

http://www.example.com/how-to-keep-your-teeth-free-of-stains.html

using Apache mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file.  I've tried several ways, but I can't get my RewriteRule to match the broken URLs.  Is this possible at all, and if so, how?

Comment: Hi, yuan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question a bit to hopefully clarify it, but it's always possible that I might have made some mistakes while doing so. Please check if my edits match what you wanted to ask, and if not, feel free to edit the question yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible, e.g. like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^"http:/+www\.example\.com/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,NS,R=301]
```

Note that Apache will automatically decode the `%22` into a double quote (`"`), so that's what you need to match in your [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).  Also, the browser and/or Apache will automatically normalize the double slash in `"http://` into a single slash, before mod_rewrite even sees it.  In the rule above, I've used `/+` to ensure that the regexp will match any number of consecutive slashes (greater than zero).

That said, you really should (also) fix the broken HTML code that's causing such mangled URLs to be requested in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Just wondering where I can get rewriterule information, should I go mod_rewrite page to learn? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html or you know better place, Thanks so much.

Comment: That's the best (single) place I know of. You might find [this introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) useful too, although it's a bit old and missing some newer features. There are of course also lots of mod_rewrite questions on SO (and other SE sites), but the information there can be a bit scattered. And you can find plenty of tutorials by Googling e.g. for "rewriterule tutorial", although I'm not familiar enough with them to really recommend any specific one.

Comment: Thanks! your answer is great!